# How do you get the value of a dropdown list and make it an Input variable in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

The website that I'm making, using Laravel and Bootstrap, has a search bar along with a dropdown list, that will narrow the search down to a specific category. Here's the following code for the search bar:

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="search_form" method="get" action="{{ route('search') }}">
        <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span name="category" id="search_concept">Title</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#title">Title</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#author">Author</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#school">School</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#course_code">Course Code</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">-->         
                    <input class="form-control" name="term" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" id="filter">
                    <span id="search_submit" type="submit" class="btn input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="width:1%;"></span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I type "hello world" into the search bar and submit the form, I get redirected to this URL: `http://localhost:8000/search?term=hello+world`
I want to also pick up the selected value of the dropdown list, so when I select 'title' as my category in the dropdown list and submit the form, I would get redirected to:

```
http://localhost:8000/search?category=title&term=hello+world
```

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify it like this and use jQuery/js

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="search_form" method="get" action="{{ route('search') }}">
        <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span name="category" id="search_concept">Title</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a data-category="title" class="search_category" href="#title">Title</a></li>
                          <li><a data-category="author" class="search_category" href="#author">Author</a></li>
                          <li><a data-category="school" class="search_category" href="#school">School</a></li>
                          <li><a data-category="course_code" class="search_category" href="#course_code">Course Code</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">-->         
                     <input type="hidden" name="category" id="category"/>
                    <input class="form-control" name="term" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" id="filter">
                    <span id="search_submit" type="submit" class="btn input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="width:1%;"></span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".search_category").click(function(e){
    $("#category").val($(this).attr("data-category"));
});
```

Comment: I used your modification, and I had to make a small change to your hidden input tag, where I've added the value attribute, so that jQuery can change it according to the category that was selected. And voila, my problem was solved! Thanks!

Comment: yes; the value attr will be the default value if the user didn't select. you can play with font awesome to add fa-check or some sort like that to show selected item on your dropdown;